# Did not schedule build for branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am just starting with jenkins. And I am trying to run a build on a branch/master.

And all I am getting is Did not schedule build for branch: master

Here is the log:

```
Started by timer
[Sun Mar 05 18:23:43 NPT 2017] Starting branch indexing...
Connecting to https://bitbucket.org using sameerkattel@hotmail.com/****** (sameer_kattel)
Repository type: Git
Looking up sameer_kattel/protected-consumer for branches
Checking branch single_page_app from sameer_kattel/protected-consumer
Checking branch master from sameer_kattel/protected-consumer
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
Met criteria
Changes detected: master (null → b2e24fc7a3a3c68f84dddf69d2cedc79f8478bf3)
Did not schedule build for branch: master
Checking branch enable_cors_response_lamda from sameer_kattel/protected-consumer
Looking up sameer_kattel/protected-consumer for pull requests
[Sun Mar 05 18:23:45 NPT 2017] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 2.1 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

How do I schedule a branch?? Here is my JenkinsFile

```
#!groovy

node {

    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

    try {

       stage 'Build'

            checkout scm
            dir(spa)
            sh 'npm install'
            sh 'ng build'
        }

    catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
         echo 'failed' 
        throw err
    }
}
```

Can some one point me to right direction??

Comment: Did you find a solution to this???

Comment: I know that this question is old, but I have this issue nowadays. Did you resolved this somehow?

Comment: Just had this issue and it seems to have mysteriously solved itself after I went into the config and hit 'verify' for the credentials. I didn't even save the (lack of) config changes. I've had a lot of these types of issues with Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion found in some [old IRC logs](https://botbot.me/freenode/jenkins/2016-08-10/?msg=71112916&page=7) is that the "Automatic branch project triggering" option has been set to something that doesn't match the branch you want built.  Set that option appropriately so that your desired branch or branches will build automatically.

Answer (score 2):

As [oueftete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496971/5228524) suggests, make sure the "Automatic branch project triggering" regex matches your branch.

What I didn't realize (after coming back to this page and rereading that answer multiple times over the last year and a half) is that, unlike in python, a blank regex does NOT match everything.  If you want to build every branch, you have to put `.*` in that field.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Heshy and @oeuftete answer:

- To me it seems that "automatic branch project triggering" only means to *create* a job for a given branch. It does not imply running a first build whatsoever.
- I also experienced that even if you send a HTTP request from a VCS, such as gitlab, even if Jenkins replies with HTTP 200 it does not mean that it will actually run the build. You need to explicitly instruct jenkins to actually *react* upon such an incoming webhook call. You might further configure what jenkins reacts to (filter). In jenkins' philosophy it does not react without any further ado, just because a wild webhook is received. You need a *trigger setting* in your project to to react on such trigger. How you do this depends on the VCS you use. With gitlab this is achieved by the `triggers { gitlab(...) }` method call. See [GitLab plugin documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/). Here you can set whether or not MR changes are *triggered* upon, etc... To configure this, the "Build when change is pushed to gitlab" checkbox in the branch's configuration page, which is of course set through your jenkinsfile because this is branch specific setting.
- Now, regarding the initial build... I solve this using the "Build strategies" feature of Branch API Plugin. In the project configuration page "Add" -> "Regular branches"..