# Job build not triggered after repository scan on Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline (changes detected)

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have set git post-commit hook which triggers scan on my Multibranch Pipeline. This scan detects changes (new commit) but do not triggers building job for changed branch.

```
Scan Multibranch Pipeline Log

Branch indexing

... git messages ...

Checking branches...
  Checking branch develop
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
No changes detected: develop (still at 5ed9c9a76ef81bf023c1ea89c7515458e8ac548d)
  Checking branch master
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
No changes detected: master (still at c9ac551806eb5a90dccf093e58c907f330407b9b)
  Checking branch feature/Model
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
Changes detected: feature/Model (2e5a898498e138737941a907969eb80ee533a900 → b931de01b1f8dd51a2646f109b185592ea941f7f)
Did not schedule build for branch: feature/Model
Processed 3 branches
...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

And as a result now I have to start all jobs manually.

I've found similar issue: [Did not schedule build for branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608490/did-not-schedule-build-for-branch) but there is no answer how to fix this issue.

Can you help?

Comment: which is the changed branch? feature/Model?

Comment: yes feature/Model is branch which should be build

Answer (score 7):

For others who will face similar problem:

Be sure to don't have set property:

**(Deprecated )Suppress automatic SCM triggering**

in "Branch sources" section of Multibranch Pipeline configuration. this kills received trigger and build is not started. After removing this property builds are done just after you commit them.

Comment: This worked, but strangely, my other pipelines have this set and is still being scheduled correctly.

Comment: Same with us. We have a few pipelines with this setting that still trigger the first build after branch detection and it helps to automatically set params and triggers. Also, I remember seeing this working as expected for all our pipelines, so this may be a regression in one of the upgrades we did. Unfortunately, we can't remove `Suppress automatic SCM triggering` because we don't want the builds to be triggered with all changes, instead we only want the build to be triggered with the initial branch detection.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that in Build Strategies, I specified specific branches I wanted to run. By removing the named branches, the builds started to automatically build.

Even when using the wildcard for all branches, it would not build. I had to remove named branches altogether.